# Issues cleaning my project and importing R after update

Tags: android-studio

I just updated Android Studio (0.8.14) and got bombarded with various errors.

When I try to clean my project, I get this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\----\Documents\Android Projects\----\app\build\intermediates
```

Every class that imports com.myorg.myproject.R says:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'R'.
```

I checked my androidmanifest and it's referencing the package correctly.  Any idea how to fix this?

`gradlew clean` in the terminal works without error, but the clean function from the Build menu throws this error.

```
C:\Users\----\Documents\Android Projects\---->gradlew clean
:app:clean                                                                       

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.43 secs
```

Thanks